# Nested excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

There is a formula I would like to edit in excel

This is the original formula: `=IF(AF22 = 0, 0, ROUND(((AG22)) * (AU22 /BE22), 2))`

```
AF = Payment
AG = Gross Interest
AU = Fee
BE = Rate
```

I would like to add in a logic that says; IF AS = # then do this calculation:
`=ROUND((AF29*(E29/360)*30),2)`
else do the original calculation.

Is there a way to do this all in one formula??

AS is a numeric value.

Thank you fro your help!

Comment: What does `AS=#` mean? In this example are you asking if `AS22` is numeric?

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(AS22), ROUND((AF29*(E29/360)*30),2), IF(AF22 = 0, 0, ROUND(((AG22)) * (AU22 /BE22), 2)))
```

This looks like what you're looking for. Just change the reference in the `ISNUMBER` function to suit your need.